# perl sorting array: leave an item starts with # in-place

Tags: perl, sorting

Is there a way to modify sort that any string starts with # is ignored i.e. keep its index?

For example:

```
my @stooges = qw(
        Larry
        Curly
        Moe
        Iggy
    );

my @sorted_stooges = sort @stooges;
```

`@sorted_stooges` should give:

```
Curly
Iggy
Larry
Moe
```

Now, if i add # to Curly

```
my @stooges = qw(
            Larry
            #Curly
            Moe
            Iggy
        );

my @sorted_stooges = sort @stooges;
```

i would like @sorted_stooges to be:

```
Iggy
#Curly
Larry
Moe
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In-place solutions:

```
my @indexes_to_sort = grep { $array[$_] !~ /^#/ } 0..$#array;
my @sorted_indexes = sort { $array[$a] cmp $array[$b] } @indexes_to_sort;
@array[@indexes_to_sort] = @array[@sorted_indexes];
```

or

```
my @indexes_to_sort = grep { $array[$_] !~ /^#/ } 0..$#array;
@array[@indexes_to_sort] = sort @array[@indexes_to_sort];
```

or

```
my $slice = sub { \@_ }->( grep { !/^#/ } @array );
@$slice[0..$#$slice] = sort @$slice;
```

(Unfortunately, `@$slice = sort @$slice;` doesn't work —It replaces the elements of `@$slice` rather than assigning to them— but a suitable alternative was found.)

Comment: Nice answer! The last example was quite interesting.. I knew that arguments to a `sub` is always passed by reference in Perl, but it didn't occur to me it also applied to `grep` when called as part of an argument list!

Answer (score 5):

Extract the elements to be sorted, then update the original array with the sorted elements:

```
my @stooges = qw( Larry #Curly Moe Iggy );
my @sorted_items = sort grep { not /^#/ } @stooges;
my @sorted_stooges = map { /^#/ ? $_ : shift @sorted_items } @stooges;
say for @sorted_stooges;
```

In their answer, @ikegami suggests a variant of this approach where the indexes of the elements to be sorted are extracted, rather than the elements themselves. That solution allows the array elements to be exchanged elegantly with a list slice.

Comment: Your solution doesn't require the sort to be in-place like mine do.